# QML QtQuick.Controls 2.2 Combobox doesn't have selectByMouse; What is the alternative?

Tags: qt, qml, mouse, qtquickcontrols2

We are using QtQuick.Controls 2.2 and can't downgrade due to various reasons. When we use `Combobox` util from QML, it doesn't appear with `selectByMouse` field which was introduced in 1.4 version.

Our requirement is -- to be able to select the text in the combobox for copying purpose as well as have a dropdown menu.

How to fix this issue; Is there any alternative?

Comment: A "copy" button?

Comment: Report a bug, and in the meanwhile, as a workaround, set it to true yourself: `Component.onCompleted: cbox.contentItem.selectByMouse = true`

Comment: sorry, only just noticed after posting my answer that you already said in the comment above.

Answer (score 5):

You can just alter the `contentItem` to be a `TextField` of with the properties of your choice. This might look like this:

```
ComboBox {
    id: control
    model: ['Hallo', 'Hello', 'Sallut', 'Godan Dagin']
    editable: true

    contentItem: TextField {
        text: control.editText
        selectByMouse: true
    }
}
```

Note that, if you edit the text, and `editText` is not an element of your model, it will not be accepted to be the `displayText`.

This works for `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` onwards, as the properties `editable` and `editText` need to exist. Then it will automatically copy the edited text back to `displayText` once it is a valid input.
For earlier versions, this is much harder to achieve.

Comment: Overriding the default contentItem can be a pain because you lose lots of the default original behavior, unless you copy all the bindings and properties from the TextField in ComboBox.qml that ships with the Qt framework.

Comment: Or put a different way, the default contentItem TextField implementation has quite a few properties and bindings set, which are absent from this answer. Would any significant behavior be lost by omitting them?

Comment: The relevant property bindings I could think of are automatically created from the outside... Examples are the automatic live proposals of valid inputs as well as the update of the `control.displayText`. Property bindings I omitted for readability reasons are styling properties like color for different states e.t.c. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox

Comment: I do prefer this answer because it uses a documented property of the `ComboBox` rather than making any assumptions about the `contentItem`

Answer (score 4):

As of Qt 5.9 / Quick Controls 2.2, the `ComboBox` now contains a `TextField` to show the current text, if the `ComboBox` is set as `editible`. TextField does have the `selectByMouse` property you require, only it is not exposed as a property of the `ComboBox` so it is not accessible by QML. However, it can be accessed in the javascript, e.g. from the Component.onCompleted attached signal handler.

For example:

```
ComboBox {
    editable: true

    model: ListModel {
        id: model
        ListElement { text: "Banana" }
        ListElement { text: "Apple" }
        ListElement { text: "Coconut" }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        contentItem.selectByMouse = true
    }
}
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some additional info regarding **how** your code solves the problem at hand. Doing so aids those with similar (but not identical) problems. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)